# Run a command on every file in a directory, changing the output name

Tags: linux, bash

I need to compile all of the C files in a directory into seperate outputs... see example
`gcc -Wall program1.c -o program1.out`

How do I do this?

Comment: You'd need to at least tell us which operating system and shell you're using.

Comment: Bash. I only need to do this once, I used to have a script and I remember it had some regex to make `test.c.out` into `test.out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100):

```
for f in *.c; do gcc -Wall "$f" -o "${f%%.c}.out"; done
```

No need for complicated regular expressions or anything that's not a shell builtin here.