# Resize more than one image using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder containing `JPG` images and need to re-size them to a different pixel width and height and save them to a different folder with the same file name as original

> ffmpeg -i Original.JPG -vf scale=1200:900 output.JPG

this is the command i used to re-size a single image.But I need to do it for the bulk.

Any Help ?

Comment: I didn't knew that it is possible to resize JPEG with ffmpeg.exe! Thanks!

Comment: Voted as a duplicate of a Windows question. Since you're not specifying your OS, it's hard to give an exact answer, but generally you should be looking at how to loop over all files in a directory and execute a command on them, which is *fairly* easy to find, I think.

Comment: Your Linux answer is here: http://superuser.com/questions/777782/run-a-command-on-every-file-in-a-directory-changing-the-output-name

Comment: In Linux shell script    `for f in *.png; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf scale=1200:900 "../another-folder/${f%%.png}.png"; done`

Comment: When you want to batch resize multiple files with 001.jpg 002.jpg etc scheme, you can just:
`ffmpeg -f image2 -i "%03d.jpg" -vf scale="1200:900" "another-folder/%03d.jpg"`. Of course you can also png instead of jpg.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a simple Perl script that will do that for you. Check out this post which has a foreach loop which cycles through all the files in a directory. You could easily modify this and create a script to resize all your files.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1045792/3362463